# How to reference a PL/SQL Function within a Plugin's Anonymous Code Block in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, plugins, oracle-apex

I'm just starting to develop a simple plugin with Oracle Apex 5.1 and I can see I have some common requirements within the Render and Ajax Procedures that usually I would make a function for. I've searched high and low and I cannot find away to reference another function included in the Anonymous code Block from within the Render/Ajax procedures - is there some kind of syntax I'm missing?

For info, I am using the Plugins Anonymous Code Block rather than a Package to deploy the relevant procedures.

```
PROCEDURE render_item (p_item in apex_plugin.t_item,
                      p_plugin in apex_plugin.t_plugin,
                      p_param in apex_plugin.t_item_render_param,
                      p_result in out nocopy apex_plugin.t_item_render_result) IS
    lv_test VARCHAR2(1);
    BEGIN
        ...
        lv_test := myFunction();
        ...
    END;

PROCEDURE ajax_item (
    p_item   in            apex_plugin.t_item,
    p_plugin in            apex_plugin.t_plugin,
    p_param  in            apex_plugin.t_item_ajax_param,
    p_result in out nocopy apex_plugin.t_item_ajax_result ) IS
    lv_test VARCHAR2(1);
    BEGIN
        ...
        lv_test := myFunction();
        ...
END;

FUNCTION myFunction(p_x IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
BEGIN
    ...
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe gold for someone one day. After a few days searching, I came across [this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/3772687745/) that pointed towards a very simple solution.

The function must be listed BEFORE any calls to it.

```
FUNCTION myFunction(p_x IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
BEGIN
    ...
END;

PROCEDURE render_item (p_item in apex_plugin.t_item,
                      p_plugin in apex_plugin.t_plugin,
                      p_param in apex_plugin.t_item_render_param,
                      p_result in out nocopy apex_plugin.t_item_render_result) IS
    lv_test VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
    ...
    lv_test := myFunction();
    ...
END;
```